# Entity Framework nao está salvando todas as informacoes da lista

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Estou com um problema que nao consigo resolver de forma alguma com o Entity Framework.

Nesse cenário estou recebendo informacoes do front, e entao preciso salva-las no banco de dados, porem, quando tenho 2 informacoes onde o FileId é igual e o UseCaseId e o campo Order sao diferentes. Somente 1 linha é salva.

**UseCaseId e FileId** sao Chaves estrangeiras de outras tabelas, o relacionamento está logo abaixo:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
            .HasIndex(ct => ct.FileId)
            .IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
            .HasIndex(ct => ct.UseCaseId)
            .IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
            .HasKey(cn => cn.ContentId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
            .HasOne(cn => cn.File)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
            .HasOne(cn => cn.UseCase)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Nesse exemplo abaixo é um caso em que dois conteudos exatamente iguais precisam ser salvos, variando somente o UseCase, porém somente o último da lista é salvo no Banco.

[image: Example]

[image: Database]

Parametro recebido no metodo.

[image: Param]

Esse é o código onde o problema ocorre:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create([FromBody] ContentJson data)
    {
        List<Content> contents = new List<Content>();
        var contentName = string.Empty;
        var array = data.content;
        int order;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            var files = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(array[i][1].ToString());

            if (files == null || files.Length == 0)
                continue;

            contentName = array[i][0].ToString();
            order = 1;

            foreach(var fileName in files)
            {
                Content content = new Content();    
                content.Order = order;
                content.UseCaseId = long.Parse(contentName);
                content.FileId = unitOfWork.FileRepository.Get(f => f.FileName.Equals(fileName)).First().FileId;
                contents.Add(content);
                order++;
            }
        }

        unitOfWork.ContentRepository.AddRange(contents);
        unitOfWork.Save();

        return Json(Ok());
    }
```

O **ContentId** é gerado automaticamente pelo Banco, EntityFramework e dotnet atualizados. Já tentei adicionar e salvar a cada iteracao, mas o mesmo problema acontece. Tentei usar Equals e HashCode, mas nao funcionou. Estou tentando de diversas formas mas nao funciona. Alguem por favor pode me ajudar ?

Alguem pode por favor me ajudar ?

Comment: Pode adicionar o `data` exatamente como é recebido pelo controller?

Comment: Adicionei, basicamente está recebendo uma string e um "Dictionary" em forma de um "Array de Array".